# How to add a subtotal row in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table with following data:

```
Name Score
A     2
B     3
A     1
B     3
```

I want a query which give the following output.

```
Name Score
A     2
A     1
Subtotal 3
B    3
B    3
Subtotal 6
```

Please help me with an SQL code

Comment: what RDBMS do you using?

Comment: You want this from SQL directly or on a report or something of the sort?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, it would be something like this:

```
select Name, Score
from (
    select Name, Score, Name as o
    from Table1 as a
    union all
    select 'Subtotal', sum(Score), Name as o
    from Table1 as a
    group by Name
) as a
order by o, score
```

But, just as @ypercube said, there're different specific implementations in different RDBMS. Your task a bit complicated, because your table doesn't have primary key, so you can emulate it with [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function. For SQL Server you can use [grouping sets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over(order by newid()) as rn
    from Table1
)
select
    case
       when grouping(c.rn) = 1 then 'Subtotal'
       else c.Name
    end as Name,
    sum(c.Score) as Score
from cte as c
group by grouping sets ((c.Name), (c.Name, c.rn))
order by c.Name;
```

Or [rollup()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over(order by newid()) as rn
    from Table1
)
select
    case
       when grouping(c.rn) = 1 then 'Subtotal'
       else c.Name
    end as Name,
    sum(c.Score) as Score
from cte as c
group by rollup(c.Name, c.rn)
having grouping(c.Name) = 0
order by c.Name;
```

Note the [grouping()](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fbf9/29) function to replace `name` column for static `'Subtotal'` string. Also note, that order of columns matters in rollup() query.

**[=> sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fbf9/3)**

Comment: Thank you Roman Pekar.. it worked man... Thanks a ton

Answer (score 23):

Some DBMS (like MySQL and SQL-Server) have the `WITH ROLLUP` modifier of the `GROUP BY` clause, that can be used for such a query:

```
SELECT pk, name,
       SUM(score) AS score
FROM tableX
GROUP BY name, pk                   -- pk is the PRIMARY KEY of the table
  WITH ROLLUP ;
```

Test at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/778e4/3)**

---

Other DBMS (SQL-Server, Oracle) have implemented the [`GROUP BY GROUPING SETS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) feature which can be used (and is more powerful than `WITH ROLLUP`):

```
SELECT pk, name,
       SUM(score) AS score
FROM tableX
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS 
  ((name, pk), (name), ());
```

Test at **[SQL-Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63261/6)**

---

@AndriyM corrected me that there is also the `GROUP BY ROLLUP` (implemented by Oracle and SQL-Server), with same results (see updated SQL-Fiddle-2 above):

```
SELECT pk, name,
       SUM(score) AS score
FROM t
GROUP BY ROLLUP 
  (name, pk) ;
```

Comment: Actually, there's also the other, standard, [ROLLUP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495.aspx "Using GROUP BY with ROLLUP, CUBE, and GROUPING SETS"): `GROUP BY ROLLUP (name, pk)` – more concise with the same result.

Answer (score 2):

What you are showing is more of a report.  You can use application logic or a reporting tool.  The first query shows the sorted list of values by player and the second query gets the actual sum.

```
select
    name,
    score
from playerscore
order by name asc

select
    name,
    sum(score)
from playerscore
group by name
```

Answer (score -4):

SQL is not designed to list your rows of output, and then print a total each time a row changes values.  Such an output is really best done at the application level, where you would order your SQL output by "A", keep adding to subtotal on the score column, and then when the application detects a change to "B" it would insert a row as you have shown here, displaying the subtotal.  Then it would reset the subtotal when changing to "B".   I would start with Select Name, Score from Table Order by Name and then handle the rest in the application.  I would really consider if you need the rows of individual score results because if you could skip them from this query, then you could do your totals directly with SQL server but you would only get the totals by name.

Comment: That's exactly what `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` can do - and even more complex subtotals - so **SQL is designed for that as well**.