# Sum column values and append as last row in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some records in a table and i want to show all records from that table after that i want to show the sum of corresponding columns then what will be the sql query for this problem ??
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3R25.png)
Please find the Input and Expected output in the attachment.

Thanks

Comment: Please include any sample data, what you have tried, expected result, and how your results are different *in the question as text* (images cannot be quickly pasted into a test environment).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387650/how-to-add-a-subtotal-row-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

Use [*ROLLUP*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#group-by-rollup) :

```
select coalesce(category, 'Total') as Category,
       sum(a) as A,
       . . . 
from table
group by rollup(category);
```

Answer (score 0):

To test: http://rextester.com/HUE40725

This would do the job for you:

```
SELECT         Category = CASE WHEN GROUPING(Category) = 0 THEN Category ELSE 'Total' END,
        A = SUM(A),
        B=SUM(B),
        C = SUM(C),
        D=SUM(D),
        Total = SUM(Total)
   FROM dbo.NameTable
  GROUP BY Category WITH ROLLUP
 HAVING GROUPING(Category) = 0
 OR GROUPING(Category) = 1
;
```