# How to add subtotal and total in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subtotal

I want to add the total and subtotal to the result in Oracle

```
SELECT b.org_id  "Org ID", a.org_nm  "Org Name", b.trans_cd  "Transaction", TO_CHAR(b.creat_ts,'mm/dd/yyyy') "Date", b.trans_am "Amount"
FROM adrs a, advrg_fee b 
WHERE  a.org_id = b.org_id AND to_char(b.creat_ts,'yyyy') = 2019 AND to_char(b.creat_ts,'mm') = 04;
```

The result is like

```
Org ID  Org Name  Transaction    Date        Amount

  11       AA        T1         2018-4-11     100
  11       AA        T1         2018-5-11     200
  22       BB        T2         2017-9-7      200
  22       BB        T4         2018-9-11     100
```

Now I want to add subtotal and total to the result.

```
Org ID  Org Name  Transaction    Date        Amount

  11       AA        T1         2018-4-11     100
  11       AA        T1         2018-5-11     200
  AA_subtotal                                 300
  22       BB        T2         2017-9-7      200
  22       BB        T4         2018-9-11     100
  BB_subtotal                                 300
  Total                                       600
```

How can I do that? I tried the function like rollup but not sure how to use it. Any suggestion for How to modify the query? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to have `subtotal` and `total` records inside the result set besides other records, they must have the same number of column as others. In what column do you want to put the `subtotal` and `total` names in?

Comment: http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-rollup/

Comment: You should find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387650/how-to-add-a-subtotal-row-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT af.org_id as "Org ID", a.org_nm as "Org Name",
       af.trans_cd as "Transaction",
       TO_CHAR(af.creat_ts, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as "Date",
       SUM(af.trans_am) as "Amount"
FROM adrs a JOIN
     advrg_fee af
     ON  a.org_id = af.org_id 
WHERE af.creat_ts >= DATE '2019-04-01' AND af.creat_ts < DATE '2019-05-01'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (af.org_id, a.org_nm, af.trans_cd, TO_CHAR(af.creat_ts, 'mm/dd/yyyy') ), (a.org_nm), () );
```

Note the changes I have made to the query:

- This uses proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Date comparisons are used, instead of invoking functions.  This is both clearer and makes it easier for the optimizer.
- The table aliases are abbreviations for the table name, so the query is easier to follow.