# Get sum of alias sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to get the sum of the alias in SQL? I want to get the sum of the alias. I've tried a query but I got this syntax error near SELECT(sum_total). Thanks for your help!

**Query:**

```
SELECT td.expense_check_date
    ,td.expense_cn
    ,td.expense_vendor
    ,SUM(tt.expense_total - tt.expense_vat) AS sum_total
    ,SUM(SELECT (sum_total) AS total 
FROM tbl_expense_details td 
    INNER JOIN tbl_expense_transactions tt ON td.expense_id = tt.expense_details_id 
WHERE td.expense_check_date BETWEEN '2020-12-15' AND '2021-01-01' 
GROUP BY td.expense_cn, td.expense_check_date 
ORDER BY td.expense_check_date ASC)
```

Comment: You cannot access the alias in the same `SELECT` clause. You need to implement an outer query and access it from there. But even so, what would be the point in copmputing `SUM(sum_total)`? If grouping remains the same then `SUM(sum_total)` should be equal to `sum_total`.

Comment: I think you might be looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387650/how-to-add-a-subtotal-row-in-sql

Comment: Your question needs sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways:

- Window functions
- Sub Query / Common Table Expression

*Window function*

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

These functions allow different slices to apply within the same query. Therefore their performance is often better in comparison to subquery and CTE approach.

```
SELECT 
  td.expense_check_date,
  td.expense_cn,
  td.expense_vendor,
  SUM(tt.expense_total - tt.expense_vat) AS sum_group,
  SUM(tt.expense_total - tt.expense_vat)
    OVER ( PARTITION BY td.expense_check_date )
    AS total 
FROM tbl_expense_details td 
  INNER JOIN tbl_expense_transactions tt 
    ON  td.expense_id = tt.expense_details_id 
WHERE 
  td.expense_check_date BETWEEN '2020-12-15' AND '2021-01-01' 
GROUP BY 
  td.expense_cn, td.expense_check_date 
ORDER BY 
  td.expense_check_date ASC
```

Actual SQL in mySQL might differ!
This window function delivers sums by expense_cn and expense_check_date and a total sum by expense_check_date. (If a full total is required, remove the PARTITION BY clause).

*Sub query / CTE*

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Sub query is always an option though it means accessing the same table for the same query twice. If there are lots of rows to query then this will be bad for performance.
More than likely a CTE performs better.
(In the background this access the queried tables once, builds a summary in temp or memory and uses it subsequently for the next step.)

However in this case the full sum needs to be built first and then referenced, making this a subquery approach (performance!).

Like:

```
WITH
  cteSumByDate
(
  expense_check_date,
  sum_date
)
AS
(
  SELECT 
    td.expense_check_date,
    SUM(tt.expense_total - tt.expense_vat) AS sum_date
  FROM tbl_expense_details td 
    INNER JOIN tbl_expense_transactions tt 
      ON  td.expense_id = tt.expense_details_id 
  WHERE 
    td.expense_check_date BETWEEN '2020-12-15' AND '2021-01-01' 
  GROUP BY 
    td.expense_check_date 
)
SELECT
  td.expense_check_date,
  td.expense_cn,
  td.expense_vendor,
  SUM(tt.expense_total - tt.expense_vat) AS sum_group,
  ctesum.sum_date
FROM
  cteSumByCnAndDate cteSum
FROM tbl_expense_details td 
  INNER JOIN tbl_expense_transactions tt 
    ON  td.expense_id = tt.expense_details_id 
  INNER JOIN cteSumByDate ctesum
    ON  ctesum.expense_check_date = td.expense_check_date 
  WHERE 
    td.expense_check_date BETWEEN '2020-12-15' AND '2021-01-01' 
  GROUP BY 
    td.expense_check_date
```

*Remarks*

I personally think the grouping is still wrong in these queries as not all shown elements are in the GROUP BY clause.